# Why does WebClient.UploadValues overwrites my html web page?

Tags: c#, post, webclient, system.net

I'm familiar with Winform and WPF, but new to web developing. One day saw [WebClient.UploadValues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/1518100) and decided to try it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var values = new NameValueCollection();
        values["thing1"] = "hello";
        values["thing2"] = "world";
        //A single file that contains plain html
        var response = client.UploadValues("D:\\page.html", values);
        var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

After run, nothing printed, and the html file content becomes like this:

```
thing1=hello&thing2=world
```

Could anyone explain it, thanks!

Comment: Maybe worth looking at the new and shiny thing from the rest world called httpclient, it mimics http in a more natural way - just my 2 cents .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UploadValues` method is intended to be used with the HTTP protocol. This means that you need to host your html on a web server and make the request like that:

```
var response = client.UploadValues("http://some_server/page.html", values);
```

In this case the method will send the values to the server by using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding and it will return the response from the HTTP request.

I have never used the `UploadValues` with a local file and the [`documentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't seem to mention anything about it. They only mention HTTP or FTP protocols. So I suppose that this is some side effect when using it with a local file -> it simply overwrites the contents of this file with the payload that is being sent.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `WebClient` not as it was intended.

The purpose of `WebClient.UploadValues` is to upload the specified name/value collection to the resource identified by the specified URI.

But it should not be some **local file** on your disk, but instead it should be some **web-service** listening for requests and issuing responces.